# Parse substrings in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string that I'm looking to parse to get two strings from within it.

```
NSString *responseData = [object objectForKey:@"loc"];
```

The content of the variable is:

```
(
    "-79",
    "43"
)
```

How can I get the value of -79 and 43, stripping quotes and everything else?

Comment: what happens if you run this code: `NSLog("%@", [object objectForKey:@"loc"][0])` ?

Comment: `[object objectForKey:@"loc"];` seems to be a `NSArray`. So `objectAtIndex:`?

Comment: I strongly suspect that `responseData` is an NSArray, not an NSString.

Comment: It is an NSArray and [object objectForKey:@"loc"][0] does it. Thank you!

Comment: @Undo if you want to post that Answer I'll accept, thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, one would need to tack on an `intValue` call to get the numeric value rather than the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data is an `NSArray` - so you can use either `objectAtIndex:` or subscripting (`[]`). I prefer subscripting:

```
NSArray *array = object[@"loc"];

NSString *firstNumber = array[0];
NSString *secondNumber = array[1];
```